# array_unique and PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser giving duplicate values

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I have a simple [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_quickstart) setup to get external dofollow links and to get all internal links and print the results:

```
$url = "http://example.com";
$domain = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($url);
$result = array();
$result1 = array_unique($result);

foreach($html->find('a') as $a){
    $href = $a->href;
    if (strpos($href, '://')!==false AND strpos($href, $domain)==false AND isset($e->rel)==false) 
    { $result1[] = $href; echo $href.'<br />';}
}

foreach($html->find('a') as $a){
    $href = $a->href;
    if (strpos($href, '://')==false or strpos($href, $domain)!==false) 
    { $result1[] = $href; echo $href.'<br />';}
}
```

For some reason `array_unique` is not working and printed list of internal links contains duplicates.

How to make it to work?

Comment: Call to array_unique AFTER push all items.

Comment: Show us contents of `$result`

Comment: As u_mulder says, show us the content of the variables when the scripts is finished. Try putting this in the final of the script:
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result);
echo '</pre>';
echo '<pre>';
print_r($result1);
echo '</pre>';

Comment: @RodrigoTechera here it is `Array
(
)
Array
(
    [0] => http://www.example.com
)`

Answer (score 0):

Well, at the final of the script actually, $result1 array is not a unique, because you are creating it just before to do anything and from $result that is a empty array.
As @Deep says you need to put that after push all items

Try this:

```
...
$result = array();

foreach($html->find('a') as $a){
    $href = $a->href;
    if (strpos($href, '://')!==false AND strpos($href, $domain)==false AND isset($e->rel)==false) 
    { $result[] = $href; echo $href.'<br />';}
}

foreach($html->find('a') as $a){
    $href = $a->href;
    if (strpos($href, '://')==false or strpos($href, $domain)!==false) 
    { $result[] = $href; echo $href.'<br />';}
}

$result1 = array_unique($result);
...
```

Comment: I moved it to the bottom - same result. Both `$result` and `$result1` echoed `Array ()` when I did a variable contents check